# Pass and instance to a method with Action as parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I have the following method:

```
IdentityBuilder IServiceCollection.AddIdentityCore<User>(Action<IdentityOptions> setupAction)
```

Which I use as follows:

```
  services.AddIdentityCore<User>(x => {
    x.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
  })
```

This works but I tried to create a class with default values:

```
public class IdentityDefaultOptions : IdentityOptions {
  public IdentityDefaultOptions() {
    Password.RequiredLength = 8;
  }
}
```

And use it as follows:

```
services.AddIdentityCore<User>(x => new IdentityOptions())
```

It compiles but Password.RequiredLength is not applied.

What am I missing?

Comment: The action is being applied to the action parameter. By creating your own instance you are not interacting with the instance passed in by the caller of the action. What you need to do is find the source code of that extension method and write your own that used your instance.

Comment: Source code here https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L33

Comment: Note how they are applying configuration to the options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are simply creating a new instance that will never be used.
It is doing something like this:

```
public void Test(IdentityOptions options)
{
   new IdentityOptions()
}
```

That makes no sense at all.

Instead, you have to interact with the `x` object and set its values. It would be equals to:

```
public void Test(IdentityOptions options)
{
   options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
}
```

You might take a look at the [delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/using-delegates), [anonymous methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/delegate-operator) and [lambda](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions) and ['=>' operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-operator) documentation

Answer (score 2):

The function

```
 services.AddIdentityCore<User>(x => {
    x.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
  })
```

doesn't return any value,
it change the value of `x` that arrived as a parameter.

You have to get a `IdentityOptions` parameter and change the passed object.

```
public void DefaultIdentityOptions(IdentityOptions x)
{
  x.Password.RequiredLength = 8;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to create a different type?

If you are trying to configure the `IdentityOptions` instance in multiple places, or use dependency injection to make other decisions about this configuration. You can instead configure a service that implements `IConfigureOptions<IdentityOptions>`;

```cs
    public class MoreIdentityOptions : IConfigureOptions<IdentityOptions>{
        public MoreIdentityOptions(/* inject types */){}
        public void Configure(IdentityOptions options){
            x.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
        }
    }


    services.AddIdentityCore<User>();
    services.AddTransient<IConfigureOptions<IdentityOptions>, MoreIdentityOptions>();
```